# Ubuntu 19.10 stuck at purple screen after login

Tags: login, 19.10

After a simple Ubuntu update, I cannot log in anymore. When I boot up my Dell Inspiron 7548, everything works fine, I enter my drive encryption password, Ubuntu boots up, I enter my account password, hit enter, and then Ubuntu freezes at a purple screen. There is no mouse icon, my computer's fans don't spin, just nothing happens. I can still access TTY via Ctrl+Alt+F3. I did a full Ubuntu reinstall half a year ago and am not running dual boot. Ctrl+Alt+F1 will take me back to the login screen but the same thing happens when I try to log in. Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the X server logs? /var/log/Xorg.[x].log ([x] is 0, 1, 2, etc). This might help you see what's going on.

Comment: Are you dual booting? Using nvidia third party drivers?

Comment: It may be helpful to include more details about your PC configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers! I did check out the Xorg logs and something was wrong with the display settings or drivers. I tried fixing it but ended up copying my files to an external disk through TTY and doing a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 reinstall. Just don't have the skills to fix it and an Ubuntu reinstall takes very little time anyway. Thanks everyone!